# eclipse starts debugging before clicking start/resume

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Does anyone know why my **Eclipse** (3.8 with cdt plugin) starts debugging as soon as I click on the debug button?
It normally should go to the perspective and wait for me to click `start/resume` button.
thanks

Comment: Can you make your answer more clear by explaining what are you getting and what do you want to get?

Comment: @SpongeBobFan mmmm what can i say. it is as simple as I explained above: click on debug and wait for the compiler to prepare and then elcise should activate start/stop button. But it doesn't. Sometimes it does and sometimes it doesnt! And I am not alone. the guy next to me also has the same setup and same problem.